# How to organize data without resorting to excel?

Tags: database

I'm working my way through two different Yoga books, trying to consolidate the different poses into a unified reference for personal use. Excel is very uncomfortable this, so I went with plain text in YAML format. But this seems error-prone and I was wondering what the alternatives may be?

Surely some sort of generic data gathering/ organizing software must exist for personal use?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you are looking for a tool which lets you [organize data](http://www.collatebox.com/web/spreadsheet-collaboration.html) and also collate it. You can check [CollateBox](http://www.collatebox.com).
You can organize and manage your data easily with this one.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) which is spreadsheet-like but more focused on data filtering and cleaning.

Comment: Thank you for bringing Google Refine to my notice, it's definitely a very interesting tool!

Comment: Is it worth at least an upvote? ;^)